# How to have synchronization of particular files in GIT

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I'm new to git so it might be a noob question.

I'm working in git with 2 different branch (let's call them A and B)
Both of the branch are working on a different part of the project except for one type of files.

I would like that thoses files are up to date in both of the branch:
if someone working on Branch A modify on of those files, commit and push his modifications, then someone working in branch B will have the modified files in the branch B.

What is the GIT workflow to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let me explain you:

Git basic workflow is using branches. So, let say you are working on the branch A and I am working on the branch B.

If you change a file in your branch(A) then you commit and push your changes. I have to fetch and pull the remote repository to grab the changes form the remote to my local repository. But , after that i have to merge your branch(A) with my branch(B) un order to get your changes in my branch.

basic flow is:

```
User 1 on branch(A)-some modified files
User 1 on branch(A)-commit those changes to local repo
User 1 on branch(A)-push the commited changes to remote repo

User 2 on branch(B)-fetch and pull the remote repo to grab any new commit that was pushed.
User 2 on branch(B)-merge the branch(A) into my branch(B). Now i have your changes.
```

Comment: Yeah, but the only problem is that i can't merge the whole branch A into the branch B. There are only some particular files that have to be merged, but not the rest!

Comment: Here is the difference between svn and git.  Git saves a snapshot of each file, so if a file is identical in the two branchesthen this file will not be merged.  When you merge two branches in git only the differences are transfered from one to another. There is a more advanced feature called cherry pick that will allow you to select specific files from a commit.  But by default when mergin branches,  only the deltas(differences)  are transfered.

Comment: Thank u, Cherry oick seems to be what I need! I can create a commit with only the file that need to be merged in the other branch and then cherry pick this commit!